# How to add a dialog box to the WYMEditor for catching the choice?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, return-value, paste, wymeditor

I want to add a button to WYMEditor's toolbar that will show a dialog box and paste returned value from the dialog into a content.
How can I do it?
The real code is welcomed )

Answer (score 1):

I think this already exists in WYMeditor as the 'Paste from Word' button. What additional functionality are you trying to add?

The version of WYMeditor that comes packaged with [refinerycms](http://refinerycms.org) (a rails content management system) has this functionality already. I believe they simply renamed the paste from word button.